# If user has certain number of posts, do/don't do something

Tags: wordpress, count, conditional-statements

I have a custom post type and users can submit posts from the front end using a button I've created. I want this button to only show if they have submitted less than x number of posts, else it tells them they can't submit anymore.

I am using this code to count the posts for the current user and echo the results.

```
        <?php 
        $authorid = get_current_user_id();
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'home',
            'author' => $authorid,
        ) ); 
            $count = 0;
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                $count++; 
            endwhile;
            echo 'Homes registered: ' . $count;
        wp_reset_query();?>
```

This is working great. How can I create code similar to the below to achieve this conditional button?

```
if count=<5 echo 'button'
else
'Sorry youve already submitted too many, greedy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a few ways to do this, perhaps the easiest is to simply use [count_user_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts):

```
if ( count_user_posts($authorid, 'home') < 5 ) {
    // Show the button
} else {
    echo 'Sorry youve already submitted too many, greedy';
}
```

You should also be able to count the number of posts returned by your query by using something like: `$wp_query->post_count`, rather than doing another function call.